# R: can't change point size in ggplot map with size_scale range

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial

I have made a map with ggplot which plots various longitude and latitude points on a country. I want the size of the points to correspond to the frequency column that I have in my dataframe. My dataframe looks like this:

```
Longitude   Latitude    Frequency
5.012392    52.09544    4
5.196948    52.30847    4
5.196945    52.1223     6
5.196945    52.30846    1
6.180394    53.19633    3
5.233904    52.42395    87
```

Here is my code to create the map and plot the points in ggplot:

```
ggplot() + 
         geom_polygon(data=Neth, aes(long,lat,group=group), fill="whitesmoke")+
          geom_path(data=Neth, aes(long,lat, group=group), color="black",
                   size=0.2) +
         geom_point(data=df, 
         aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, label = Frequency), colour="red", fill = "pink", pch=21, size=df$Frequency,  alpha=I(0.5)) + scale_size(range = c(1,6))
```

"Neth" is my downloaded GADM map. When I add the scale_size function nothing changes and for example the point with frequency 87 is just huge. Any help is appreciated.

Here's what my plot looks like with my actual data:
[map plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMqYe.png)

Comment: Put `size = Frequency` *inside* `aes()` for the `geom_point` layer. Remove `size = df$Frequency`.

Comment: You should also probably remove `label = Frequency`, `geom_point()` doesn't take a `label` aesthetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gregor --reinstate Monica-- said:

Put size = Frequency inside aes() for the geom_point layer. Remove size = df$Frequency